# UWP windows phone build

Tags: uwp

I have created the UWP APP and install the app bundle(AdaptiveStreaming_1.0.0.0_x86_x64_arm.appxbundle) in windows lumina 540 its showing error called:

> Can't install company app contact your company's support person for help

Please advice?

Comment: Install appx instead of appxbundle

Answer (score 0):

Before you click the ".appxbundle" file to install the app on windows mobile, you would need to install the certificate first.

> 1. Open the security certificate for the appx package, and select Install Certificate

Please check the **How do I sideload an app on mobile** section on [Sideload LOB apps in Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/sideload-apps-in-windows-10) document.